# Otherwise I would/could/might be playing now

Tags: modal-verbs, progressive-aspect

Person A: Why are you sitting here and not playing with them?

Person B:

1. My leg is injured. Otherwise I **would be playing** with them now.
2. My leg is injured. Otherwise I **could be playing** with them now.
3. My leg is injured. Otherwise I **might be playing** with them now.

Are they all correct? (Not asking about the differences between "would", "could" and "might")

Comment: They all have the exact same structure, and it's grammatical: `Modal Auxiliary` + _be_ + _playing_. Modal auxiliaries must be followed by an infinitive, like _be_. This is true of all modal auxiliaries, no matter what they mean, or what other clauses they appear with.

Comment: I think that in some parts of the US (Pennsylvania?) they can also say *Otherwise I **might could** be playing with them now*, but most "mainstream" Anglophones would agree that's ***not*** "correct".

Comment: Thank you both. In the given context, do they all make sense?

Comment: There's no context given. But I'd take (3) to show possibility-of-my-actually-playing were the leg not injured, and (1) certainty were the leg not injured. (2) probably (at least in BrE) defaults to possibility-of-my-actually-playing but could also mean that 'there would be no other barrier to my playing (selection probably apart)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all correct. If there is a difference, it is in the degree of expressed certainty. “Would” sounds like you are sure,  “could” is more like *would be able to*, and “might” is *perhaps, if the coach says so*.